# For with Return in Javascript

Tags: javascript, blockly

I want to use the for in a return with the values of the variables dropdown_number and statements_action. However, the code below is not working.

```js
  var dropdown_number = block.getFieldValue('number');
  var statements_action = Blockly.JavaScript.statementToCode(block, 'action');
  // TODO: Assemble JavaScript into code variable.
  return 'for(i = 0; i <' + dropdown_number + '; i++){' + statements_action + '}';
```

The return must bring the value in statements_action the number of times required in the dropdown_number variable.

Comment: this code smells

Comment: you need a function to have a return statement

Comment: You are deliberately generating strings that represent real code so that you can show them in the blockly editor (or elsewhere)? These strings aren't actually for executing, right?

Comment: "However, the code below is not working." I think it would help to be more specific. What is it doing/not doing? Any error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As jarmod says you are generationg string.
But the answer to your question is that you'll need to store the values you retrieve in a variable and then return it.

```
let result;
for(i = 0; i <' + dropdown_number + '; i++){
    result +=  ' + statements_action + ';
}
return result;
```